# Migratory Birds solution

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote this solution  for this [practice](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/migratory-birds/problem) on HackerRank but it doesn't work with big data " Terminated due to timeout ". I will include the question description here.

> You have been asked to help study the population of birds migrating across the continent. Each type of bird you are interested in will be identified by an integer value. Each time a particular kind of bird is spotted, its id number will be added to your array of sightings. You would like to be able to find out which type of bird is most common given a list of sightings. Your task is to print the type number of that bird and if two or more types of birds are equally common, choose the type with the smallest ID number.
>
> For example, assume your bird sightings are of types arr=[1,1,2,2,3]. There are two each of types 1 and 2, and one sighting of type 3. Pick the lower of the two types seen twice: type 1.
>
> Function Description:
>
> Complete the migratoryBirds function in the editor below. It should return the lowest type number of the most frequently sighted bird.
>   migratoryBirds has the following parameter(s):
>
> arr: an array of integers representing types of birds sighted
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains an integer denoting n, the number of birds sighted and reported in the array arr.
>
> The second line describes arr as n space-separated integers representing the type numbers of each bird sighted.
>
> Constraints
>
> 5 <= n <= 2 X 10^5
>
> It is guaranteed that each type is 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.

My code is follows.

```
    result=" "
    for i in arr:
        for j in arr:
            if arr.count(i)>=2 and arr.count(j)<2:
                result=i


            elif arr.count(i)==arr.count(j)>=2 and j<i:
                result=j         

   print(result)
```

How can I improve it?

Comment: Hi! You can post this question on codereview.stackexchange. It will be better to do so.

Comment: You're probably getting downvoted (not by me) because you haven't really explained here in your question what you're trying to do. We want self-contained questions and answers here on Stack Overflow (because what good would this question be if the linked page goes down or changes, later). Perhaps you can summarize the linked page in the question?

Comment: This appears to be tested, working code. For reviews of working code to make it more performant or idiomatic, consider codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Yes , Sure . I'm New here and didn't know that . Wish instead of  downvotes I got the reason . Thank you all.

Comment: @Blckknght  Thank you for explanation. I'm really new to coding . so as i understand stack overflow isn't platform to ask about our code.? or  the way i posted my question had problem ?.  Thank you .

Comment: You should check out the [help] for guidance on what's appropriate here on Stack Overflow. While you might get better help on CodeReview for this kind of question (optimizing for performance), I don't think your question is unacceptable here on the main Stack Overflow site, as long as it is complete and not completely dependent on a link to an external site. The edit made by another user has improved it a bit. Feel free to [edit] it further yourself to improve it (but you should usually not change your code, as that might invalidate answers that comment on what you were doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs into time out error because the complexity of your code is O(n^3).

To pass the test, you need an O(n) algorithm which can be achieved as follows.

Prepare a list of length 5, initiate them with all 0. We will use this list to count the number of birds of each type. If you prefer, using dictionary is fine too.

Now, run through the input array and increment the count. That is if you encounter type i, increment the (i-1)-th entry with 1.

Now look for the maximum count and return the corresponding index + 1.

```
def migratoryBirds(arr):
    typecount = [0 for i in range(5)]
    for i in arr:
        typecount[i-1] += 1
    max_count = max(typecount)
    for i in range(5):
        if typecount[i] == max_count:
            return i+1
```

Comment: Thank you . So there is no way to optimize my code ? I have to change my  way of thinking ? But of course i read others solution on Hackerrank but there were all lengthy  or as you mentioned using dict . Thanks again

Comment: The main concern is the complexity. Inside the two for loop, you are calling count, hence it is cubic overall.  To slightly improve it, you can precompute the count outside the loops, but that is still not sufficient as that just reduce it to quadratic.

Comment: @ Siong Thye Goh Thank you Siong . I literally did understand  half of your comment(my knowledge not enough ), but I'm thankful for your time and comments

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter


a = [int(e) for e in "1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 3 4".split(' ')]
c = Counter(a).most_common()
print(sorted([elt for elt in c if elt[1] == c[0][1]])[0][0])
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code getting timeout because of time complexity o(n3)

```
from collections import Counter
    def migratoryBirds(arr):
        arr.sort()
        result=Counter(arr)
        return(max(result, key=result.get))
```

first you need to sort the array and use counter to count the elements  and using max function you can get the desired no

Comment: 1/ Sorting before counting is useless. 2/ This doesn't satisfy the requirements of the question (what about 'Pick the lower ...' part?)

Comment: 1. i solved this problem at hackerrank . if you dont sort the array you will get 4th test case failed ...2/ you need to pick highest frequency bird highest one so you need to use max

Comment: arr=[2,4,4,1,1,9,9]
    print(Counter(arr))
    arr2=[1,1,2,4,4,9,9]
    print(Counter(arr2))
    
OUTPUT  Counter({4: 2, 1: 2, 9: 2, 2: 1})
Counter({1: 2, 4: 2, 9: 2, 2: 1})

Comment: OK, I see why you did it this way, but it's inefficient then, as sorting is O(n*log(n)) while counting is simply O(n). It would be better to count without sorting, then look at the expected result among the 5 counts.